# does firebase charge for retrieving docs from firestore js sdk cache

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

- I am using the firebase JS SDK, with [offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) enabled. This will automatically cache my retrieved documents inside the JS SDK.
- I perform this query:

```js
// once
firebase.firestore().doc('path/to/doc').get()
// twice
firebase.firestore().doc('path/to/doc').get()
```

#### My questions are:

1. Would Firebase charge me for two reads in the case **offline persistence is enabled**. Since I believe the second read would come from the offline cache without making a network call?
2. Would Firebase charge me *once* or *twice* when **offline persistence is disabled**?

#### My use case

A user opens a web-app with his 'tasks' from clients.
Each task has a `client` field with a document reference.

1. retrieve all tasks (eg. 500 reads)
2. retrieve each client document per task (another 500 reads even though some clients are the same)

So **if there are only say 20 clients**, I'd rather have only 520 reads instead of 1000 reads when the user opens the app.

Is it better to redesign my data structure to have the relevant client information saved on the task itself instead of a reference, or will the Firebase JS SDK be smart enough to not double retrieve the same doc it just retrieved.

---

PS: I found a similar question here:

[Does Firestore charge Cloud Function Get reads per retrieved documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52110856/does-firestore-charge-cloud-function-get-reads-per-retrieved-documents)

But it just didn't have the exact information I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> does firebase charge for retrieving docs from firestore js sdk cache?

No it doesn't. If a read is fulfilled from the local cache, it is not charged as a server-side read.

But your code has two `get` calls:

> ```
> // once
> firebase.firestore().doc('path/to/doc').get()
> // twice
> firebase.firestore().doc('path/to/doc').get()
> ```

And in this case, the Firestore client has no way to know whether the  document was changed between these two calls. So it has to call to the server to determine whether the document was changed, which is (or at least *may be*) a charged read.

If you need to know the current state of a document in multiple places in your app that execute close to each other (time wise), you should keep an `onSnapshot` listener on that document. This ensures that the local cache is always up to date at a minimal cost.

Comment: How about my "use case" I described, where I set a listener to retrieve 500 tasks, and need to get the client document saved as reference on each task. (eg. `forEach(taskDoc => taskDoc.clientRef.get())` ) Would this be charged as 500 extra reads even if there are many duplicate references and in total just 20 clients?

Comment: If you perform 500 `get()` operations, there are 500 reads from the server needed. But if you add a listener for each unique client, you can be sure you have the latest data with 20 listeners and reads.

Comment: So do you mean to say if I do: `firestore.firebase().collection('tasks/data').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => querySnapshot.forEach(doc => doc.data().clientRef.get()))` And my onSnapshot retrieves 500 tasks, and these 500 tasks all execute `doc.data().clientRef.get()`, then I'll be charged for 1000 reads (500 + 500), regardless if some clientRefs are the same? (if you can add the answer to this in your answer I'll mark as correct! sorry for asking a lot, I want to understand you clear)

Comment: Each `get()` has to check if the document is up to date on the server, so 500 calls to `get()` are 500 reads. I've said that both in my answer, and in my comment above.