# Will we pay (cost) for reading from cache only (Cloud FireStore)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In most cases I am writing as online, but I am reading as offline(from cache):

```
db.collection('users/user1/messages').get({ source: 'cache' });
```

Will the above code will cost me? as I am reading only from `cache` not `server`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56617814/questions-about-firestore-cache-and-reads-charge and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55202782/does-firebase-charge-for-retrieving-docs-from-firestore-js-sdk-cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Querying using only the cache using `source: 'cache'` will never incur any billing.  Only document received from the server will cost document reads.